# http javaScript set attribute default to all tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attributes, tags

I am pretty new to HTML and just trying to figure things out...

I am trying to set an attribute for the  tag, more specifically the target attribute so that all links in web page would open in a different tab...

I have encountered the jQuery functions and tried to implement it with no success...

My script tag goes like this:

```
<script src="static/jquery-3.1.1.js">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('a').target = "_blank"
        $("a").attr("target", "_blank");
    });

    $('a').target = "_blank"
</script>
```

when of course the jquery file is at the same directory under static dir as mentioned....

I have also tried the following:

```
<script>
    var elems = document.body.getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    elems.setAttribute("target","_blank");
</script>
```

when there's only one  tag in page...

Please tell me what am I doing wrong....

Thanks:)

Comment: You've embedded your code inside the external jQuery script. You need two scripts. One to fetch jQuery, and another for your code. `<script src="static/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script> <script> /* your code */ </script>`

Comment: The second code block should work for a single element, but won't if you put the script up at the top of the page, which would make it run before any elements are loaded.

Comment: And no need for jQuery: `for (let link of document.links) { link.target = "_blank" }`

Comment: Thnank you so much... you seem to have lots of knowledge in html... do you maybe by chance know why when I inspect the page using firefox/chrome and looking for the a's target ($('a').target in console) it still says undefined...? should I use maybe id's att to see it...?

Comment: Because `$("a")` makes jQuery fetch all `<a>` elements, but it returns them an a container object usually called a "jQuery object". That object itself has no `target` property. It stores each element by numeric index, much like an Array, so the first element found is at index `0`, the second at `1`, and so on. So if you did `$("a")[0].target`, you'll get the `.target` of the first element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some syntax error in your script, correct code in

```
<script src="static/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("a").attr("target", "_blank");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thnx It works now... just to know... do you maybe know why when I inspect the page using firefox/chrome and looking for the a's target ($('a').target in console) it still says undefined...? should I use maybe id's att to see it...?

Comment: @Dardar1991 if you are using `jquery` then you should have to use jquery syntax. and there is no `.target()` method. That's why we use it as a attr.

Answer (score 1):

The correct approach to set an attribute to all elements of a web page is to loop through all elements and set the attribute like so:

```js
var elems = document.body.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++)
{
  elems[i].setAttribute("target","_blank");
}
```

If using jQuery the function to set attributes is **$(selector).attr(attribute_name,value)**

Example:

```
$('a').attr("target","_blank");
```

Comment: ✔ ✔ ✔ best solution

Answer (score 0):

At first, your code should be like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").attr("target", "_blank");
});
```

It actually works. You can try it on this page. I don't know what page r u testing on, but I can guess the reason why your code didn't work is that some links are generated after the execution of your code. You can change your code as below to avoid this problem.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function(){
       $("a").attr("target", "_blank");
    },200);
});
```

You can also add some code to imporve the efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually have to modify the html, you *could* just add a click handler to every link like so.

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  window.open(this.href);
});
```

Comment: Thanx your answer worked too it's just that I was trying to get an idea of how to set all the page tag's as one attribute default (any attribute)

Comment: And just a question - is the e parameter that the function receives contains anything...? is it like sending this/self? cause I didn't send any value and it still worked....